# Spring Roo Project Command Error

Tags: java, spring, spring-roo

When I try to enter below command from roo shell:

```
project --topLevelPackage com.ch.core
```

It tries to create pom.xml and fails:

```
Created ROOT\pom.xml
Undo create ROOT\pom.xml
No enum constant org.springframework.roo.project.DependencyScope.PROVİDED
```

What can be the reason that prevents to initialize project? Using STS didn't make any difference. Thanks for helping.

*Windows 8, JDK 7. Roo 1.2.4*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a Turkish Locale issue..

No enum constant org.springframework.roo.project.DependencyScope.**PROVİDED**

it is verry common when a framework uses toUpper to look up an enum class with letter i.

'i' becomes 'İ' not 'I' in Turkish Locale environments and 'No enum constant' error occures.

you can try to force java to use english locale with

```
 java -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en
```

or you can just change your windows' system locale to english

another solution would be using capital letters when setting dependency scope if you can set it in your xml files.. 'PROVIDED' instead of 'provided'

Comment: Set Windows language to Eng. and it did the trick! Thanks and congrat. İyi bayramlar :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using STS you can edit sts.ini and add the following after -vmargs

```
-Duser.language=en
```

You don't need to change your locale.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps the package contains a reserved keyword?

Comment: No "using" demo word gives that error as well. Btw the sentences that starts with "perhaps" would be a comment not an answer.